# GnuPG - SSIS Package Error - The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0"

Tags: ssis, gnupg

I have a SSIS package which encrypts files and places the encrypted files to a shared location.
\SRV1\PROD\Files\

The server SRV1 is to be decommissioned hence I changed the connection in the SSIS packages to new location.
\SRV2\PROD\Files\

The process fails on execution.

> [Execute Process Task] Error: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" "--yes --encrypt --recipient  generic "\SRV2\PROD\Files\text.csv"" at "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuPG\bin", The process exit code was "2" while the expected was "0".

The permission on the shared folders for server SRV1 and SRV2 are same.

The package runs fine if I change the location back to SRV1.

Comment: If you log on where the SSIS package as running - with the account that the SSIS package is running under - then you can run the command within Command Prompt, and potentially add some detailed error logging, or you may see a prompt from the program (that obviously SSIS is unable to answer).  You can also just do further troubleshooting (on permissions, paths, etc.) until you get to the point that it's running successfully within Command Prompt - and at that point it should be OK in SSIS

Comment: What does the command line tell you when you run it there, from the server where this package runs, as Craig asks?